# Unable to get document page name for

Tags: xpages

I have a view that has XPage Associated with document form set.

The form property has the xpage associated with the document.

If I click on the link in the view the proper correct xpage is displayed as expected.

But if I close the browser, and paste the URL to the document into the browser, I get the error, Unable to get document page name for  (and the unid).   As long as I remain logged in the url will work without error or if I set anonymous to Reader the url will continue to work.  But if I close the browser where I would be prompted to login then I get the error but I get the error before being prompted to log in.

The url for assocated forms looks a little different than when the view is used to display the xpage.

myserver/mydb.nsf/$$OpenDominoDocument.xsp?documentId=12B571F2B03E3764852573690041E273&action=openDocument

The view has various types of forms so I need to associate the form with the xpage or I suppose I can compute the xpage for the form.   But any idea what would be causing this issue?

Answer (score 2):

If you are opening a document from a view, the associated form could be overriden by a form formula of the view. When opening the document directly with *$$OpenDominoDocument.xsp* the original form stored in the document is used instead.

The form can be associated with a XPage in different ways:

1. For XPiNC there is a field *$XPagesAltClient* in the form
2. For web access there is a field *$XPagesAlt* in the form
3. There is a entry in the *xsp.properties* file.

For example this entry...

```
xsp.domino.form.xpage.foo=bar
```

...will open a document with the value *foo* in the *Form* field with the XPage *bar.xsp*.

Hope this helps

Sven

Comment: I do not have a form forumla in the view. Also this is web only not (XPiNC).

Comment: What creates the $XpageesAlt field because I do not see it and we have aother apps that do not have it that work fine.

Comment: I added an entry of xsp.domino.form.xpage.doc=xp_fmDocument   but that did not seem to help.  My document has form set to "doc".

Comment: I aslo tried adding a $XPagesAlt field to my form with the value xp_fmDoument and that did not fix the issue.

Comment: Any other solution on this? I tried option 2 & 3, but no luck on resolving this issue.

Comment: @PrashantArkal: What about the stack trace?

Comment: Unable to post the stack trace here. how I can send it to you?

Comment: @PrashantArkal: Create a new question referencing to this one, and post the stack trace there.

Comment: @Sven Hasselbach: I have posted stack trace in new post: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34347595/xpages-console-error-unable-to-get-document-page-name-for)