# Opening different xpages forms from a view panel

Tags: xpages

I have an Xpages application that pulls data from another .nsf file. I have a view panel linked to a view in that db. The view has documents with several different forms in it. I want to be able to open each document in it's own form(xpage).

How do I write a computed At Runtime, open selected document using: statement that will select the correct Xpage to present the document.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options:

- use "use xpage associated with form" and edit the form's property
- use a SSJS formula to compute the Form. You provide a variable name in the view control **var** to access a view row as XSPViewEntry. If the Form is in a view column even one you don't display you use  .getColumnValue otherwise getDocument.getItemValueString

Does that work for you?

Answer (score 2):

If you use the Data View component instead of a View Panel, you can compute the `pageName` attribute, referencing the `var` attribute to return a different value for each row based on the document that row represents. The flexibility of the Data View component also makes it easier to make your app look more like a modern web application and less like an Excel spreadsheet. As an additional bonus, the mobile theme invokes a renderer that makes each Data View instance look like a native mobile list, so using Data Views instead of View Panels simplifies mobile development.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this mothed can help you: [Unable to get document page name for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16844120/unable-to-get-document-page-name-for)

Hope this helps

Mark

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem today. I use only one form but 3 different xpages for associated with this form. I have 3 different document types in the view. I used rowData the get the type of the document.

```
try{
    var v=rowData.getColumnValue("form");
    if(v.indexOf("x")> -1){var page ="x.xsp"}
    else if(v.indexOf("y") > -1){var page = "y.xsp"}
    else{var page = "z.xsp"}
}catch(e){
    var page = "x.xsp"
}
```

So to your view you can create a column with the value of the form and you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the extension library Dynamic View control which has an event you can code to get a handle to the NotesViewEntry which was selected. See the demo database page Domino_DynamicView.xsp and the Custom Event Handler tab for an example.

Note, in 8.5.3 (I have not upgraded yet) if you add or edit the eventHandler for onColumnClick it will be added to the XPages source as an xe:eventHandler. It needs to be an xp:eventHandler to work. The way to do it is to copy the code in the source from the exiting event and delete it. Recreate the event and update the code. Then go back into the source and change the tags within the eventHandler to xp:.

Comment: Thanks to all. I will be using the Data View instead of a view control.