# XPages Console Error: Unable to get document page name for

Tags: xpages

Referring to Question:
[Unable to get document page name for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16844120/unable-to-get-document-page-name-for/16844786?noredirect=1#comment56399401_16844786)

I have tried the solution given by Sven, but we still getting same error.
Applications are access via browsers only.

```
12/14/15 2:30 PM: Exception Thrown
Context Path: /db/common/itrs.nsf
com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: Unable to get document page name for C8AF761CF554445D48257CC90007D9AD
    at com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoDocumentPageTransformer.transformPageName(DominoDocumentPageTransformer.java:69)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.convertVirtualPage(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:690)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl._createViewRoot(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:490)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.createViewRoot(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:567)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.doCreateView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:142)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerEx.createView(ViewHandlerEx.java:90)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:251)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:157)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:576)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1335)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:853)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:796)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:565)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1319)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:662)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:482)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:357)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:313)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
Caused by: com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: Error while computing document form
    at com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoUtils.getXPagesForDocument(DominoUtils.java:603)
    at com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoDocumentPageTransformer.transformPageName(DominoDocumentPageTransformer.java:53)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: com.ibm.designer.domino.napi.NotesAPIException: Error finding special ID, Database=700 Special database object cannot be located
    at com.ibm.designer.domino.napi.NotesDatabase.NGetSpecialNoteID(Native Method)
    at com.ibm.designer.domino.napi.NotesDatabase.getSpecialNoteID(NotesDatabase.java:600)
    at com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoUtils.getXPagesForDocument(DominoUtils.java:540)
    ... 22 more
```

Thank you in anticipation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *DominoDocumentPageTransformer* doesn't fetch some errors, e.g. if the document does not exist or is not readable for the current user. Because the transformation happens during the page convertion (the XPages engine tries to interpret the URL and seeks for the XPage to open), you receive an error.

As far as I know you can overwrite the existing *PageTransformer* and catch the error for yourself.

```
package ch.hasselba.factory;

import com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoDocumentPageTransformer;
import com.ibm.xsp.page.VirtualPageTransformer;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

public class PageTransformer implements VirtualPageTransformer {

    public boolean isVirtualPage(FacesContext fc, String pageName) {
        return "/$$OpenDominoDocument.xsp".equals(pageName);
    }

    public String transformPageName(FacesContext fc, String pageName) {
        String xspPage = "/ErrorPage.xsp";
        try {
            DominoDocumentPageTransformer transformer = new DominoDocumentPageTransformer();
            xspPage = transformer.transformPageName(fc, pageName);

        } catch (Exception e) {}

        return xspPage;
    }
}
```

This opens the XPages *ErrorPage.xsp* when the transformation fails.

To activate the Transformer, you have to create the file

*/WEB_INF/com.ibm.xsp.factories.properties*

and add the line

*PageTransformer=ch.hasselba.factory.PageTransformer*

see here: http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=1028

Answer (score 0):

I know that you've probably solved the problem you had by now! But I've had the same issue and was hunting around trying to find the solution, so wanted to add my findings to this thread.

The reason I saw this error was because users were trying to open a document from a doc link within an email and there was no default form specified in that database.